# Position of function affecting output

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am converting data in POST request to upper case using streams in nodejs. I have two code snippets, one is working fine, but another snippet is behaving differently
First, which is working correct

```
var http = require('http');
var through = require('through');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        req.pipe(through(function (buf) {
            this.queue(buf.toString().toUpperCase());
        })).pipe(res);
    }
    else res.end('send me a POST\n');
    });
server.listen(parseInt(process.argv[2]));
```

Second, whose output is different

```
var http = require('http');
var through = require('through');
var tr = through(function(buf) {
    this.queue(buf.toString().toUpperCase());
    });

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
if(req.method == 'POST') {
    req.pipe(tr).pipe(res);
} else {
    res.end('Send me a post\n');
}
});
server.listen(parseInt(process.argv[2]));
```

Only difference I can notice is that in first case function is defined inside createServer method and in second it is defined outside createServer method. Is this is the reason that they are behaving differently or there is any other reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        req.pipe(through(function (buf) {
            this.queue(buf.toString().toUpperCase());
        })).pipe(res);
    }
    else res.end('send me a POST\n');
    });
```

through() will invoke every time when your request comes, so It works well. On the seconde example, you just calll this function one time, you use the same result.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you create a new `through()` stream for each request.

In the second example, you create a single `through()` stream and use it for every request.